# socket.io code structure: where to place methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

When using the socket.io library, I am a little confused about how to place the different methods.

In a very simple chat application I have `server.js`:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    //some methods to handle when clients join.   

    socket.on('text', function(msg) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('text', msg);
    });
});
```

and `client.js`:

```
var socket = io.connect();

socket.on('connect', function() {

    //some methods to fire when client joins.   

    socket.on('text', function(msg) {
        console.log(msg)
    });
});
```

Right now, the methods that handle when a client joins AND the methods that handle the sending and receiving of messages afterwards, are placed within the `connect` / `connection` event methods, both on the server and the client side, but this structure seems to work as well on the client side:

```
var socket = io.connect();    

socket.on('connect', function() {

    //some methods to fire when client joins.   

});

socket.on('text', function(msg) {
    console.log(msg)
});

+potentially many more methods...
```

My question is, what is the fundamental difference between placing a method inside the connect method and outside, and what is considered the best option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call this,

```
socket.on('xyz', function listener() {});
```

you listen for **event** `xyz` and add function `listener` as **event handler**. It is executed whenever `xyz` occurs. So when you do :

```
socket.on('connect', function() {
    socket.on('text', function(msg) {
        console.log(msg)
    });
});
```

Event handler/listener for `text` is added only when `connect` event happens (connect event handler is executed). There is only one listener before `connect` happens and two (one more) when `connect` happens. But when you do :

```
socket.on('connect', function() {
    //some methods to fire when client joins.   
});
socket.on('text', function(msg) {
    console.log(msg)
});
```

There are two listeners at any time, before/after connect happens.

The previous method is more efficient and logical. Logical because `text` cannot happen before `connect` happens, so why listen to it. Efficient as in the event-loop does not have unnecessary events to look for. Adding too many events may not hurt very much, but for performance-critical applications it can be a drag. The latter one just looks good, all event handlers placed one by one.

Comment: Thank you very much for that very clear and precise explanation, -that makes perfect sense.