# node.js + socket.io + redis + rails — RealTime application

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I need to add realtime to my application (Ruby On Rails), so, I think that the better way to do it is to use node.js + socket.io + redis.

I have this application.js file in a backend (node.js)

```
var app = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io');
var redis = require('redis').createClient();
var _ = require('underscore')._;

io = io.listen(app);
io.configure(function() {
    io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]);
    io.set("polling duration", 10);
    io.set("close timeout", 10);
    io.set("log level", 1);
})

redis.subscribe('rt-change');

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
        socket.emit('rt-change', message)
    });
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 5001;
app.listen(port);
```

And messages.js in frontend

```
 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5001/socket.io');
socket.on('rt-change', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

I'm launching application.js with *node application.js* command and it works!

> MacBook-Pro-Zhirayr:rt zhirayr$ node application.js    info  -
>   socket.io started

But when I'm trying to send message with redis ($redis.publish 'rt-change', {hello:'world'}) from Rails application, my browser doesn't log anything in console.
I'm sure, that connection from browser established, cause when I stop node, it throws connection refused error. And I'm sure that connection between redis and node established, cause console.log(message) in application.js logs it.
But console.log in browser doesn't log anything.

Any ideas why?

Thanks.

UPD for #Antoine

Added console.log in application.js
    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
            console.log('new message from redis');
            socket.emit('rt-change', message);
        });
    });

When r.publish 'rt-change', {:hello=>'world'} become executed, node logs this:

```
new message from redis
new message from redis
new message from redis
new message from redis
new message from redis
new message from redis
new message from redis
new message from redis
new message from redis
new message from redis
new message from redis
```

It's strange, node logs 11 times for 1 message.

Comment: From where do you sending this message `$redis.publish 'rt-change', {hello:'world'}` ?

Comment: Can you put a log into the redis subscribe callback to make sure that it's triggered ?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your javascript console on the browser ?

Comment: Have you tried sending message from node application.js? Put some `socket.emit('rt-change', message)` inside onConnection callback. Also are you 100% sure there is connection between browser and node app? You set transport to xhr-polling, so in console you should see "heartbeats".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5001/socket.io');
socket.on('rt-change', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

This part of the code does not seem correct, according to the doc on http://socket.io , 
you should do something like:

```
<script src="http://localhost:5001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5001');
</script>
```

Comment: Solved by myself 10 minutes ago, then I jump to stackoverflow to close ticket, and here is you answer :) Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why you are getting multiple executions for a single publish is because of the nested event-handling in your code. I will try to explain this as simple as I can.

When you call

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {...});
```

you listen for `connection` event and add the given function as event handler. It is executed whenever a new user connects. This creates a separate scope, for the execution of the handler each time.

When you call this

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
        console.log('new message from redis');
        socket.emit('rt-change', message);
    });
});
```

you add listeners for redis subscriber event `message` for each of the connected users separately. This is why you are getting multiple logs and connected users get multiple copies of same message. You got 11 messages which means there were 11 different users connected at that time.

To solve this you can call `once` instead of `on` for listening events. Like this

```
io.once('connection', function(socket) {
    redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
        console.log('new message from redis');
        socket.emit('rt-change', message);
    });
});
```

This applies to the socket.io clients also. See my previous answers to get clarity on this:

1. [socket.io code structure: where to place methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757727/socket-io-code-structure-where-to-place-methods)
2. [socket.io creates one more connection after reconnecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787996/socket-io-creates-one-more-connection-after-reconnecting)